# Best way to get both 120V and 240V from existing multiwire branch circuit (MWBC)

Tags: gfci, 240v, mwbc

I have a double pole 20A breaker feeding a 120V MWBC with 12/3 with ground, romex that goes up three levels to two separate 120V duplex GFCI receptacles with common neutral.

I want to have both 120V and 240V small appliances.  Wanting to add a 240V 6 amp coffee maker to two small 120V appliances. This is not a kitchen, but indoors, off of a top deck. The MWBC feeds just the two 120V duplex GFCI's, nothing else.

What is best practice to do this?

I could run existing MWBC wires to a small panel, then install one double pole 15A 240V GFCI breaker and two single pole 15A 120V GFCI breakers, and new receptacles. Possible also to use the existing 120V GFCI receptacles and regular single pole breakers fed off this panel too, in this situation.

Or could leave the current two GFCI receptacles alone and take 12g wire pig-tailed from the ends of the MWBC to a 'spa' panel, change out the breaker in the 'spa' panel for a 15A or 20A 240V double pole GFCI breaker and then connect a 240V receptacle.

Or I could attach an inline 240V GFCI to the hot leads of the MWBC in a junction box.

Or I could use a 2000W step up/down transformer plugged into one of the 120V GFCI receptacles. It just seems redundant to convert the voltage when I already have it there, but a plug-in transformer may be the most code compliant and cheapest, way.

I can not run another wire from my main panel. I cannot replace the 20A double pole breaker in the main panel, with a GFCI breaker, as it is actually a quad breaker.

Any other ideas? Other than code won't allow any of it? Wife really wants the coffee maker so it is going to get done somehow.

Comment: What make/model is your quadruplex breaker?

Comment: Square D HOM DP--4075, one two pole and two one pole.  handle tie across the two inner breakers.  The two inner breakers with handle tie, feed the 12/3 with ground that goes to top deck

Comment: Breaker appears to be called a Quad Tandem Circuit Breaker

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, this is a Square D HOM panel, *right?*  There are many other panels which HOM will "snap in to", however, the clip doesn't grab properly and it will arc and burn up your bus, at best making that slot dead. There are only certain cases where you can cross brands, that's where a company engineers their breaker specifically for a competitor's panel and get UL to classify it as safe.  Square D absolutely refuses to do that.

Comment: Yes, it is a Square D home panel.  This is the breaker. 20A. It is clearly common trip on the two center breakers which are connected to the circuit.. 12awg, 3 wire w/ground romex.  Sharing a neutral. 2 hots from the two center breakers.  Installed by licensed contractor and inspected by the city.  I want to run a 220V coffee maker and one or two 120V appliances from this circuit. Is it legal and reasonably safe to do so? Total appliance amperage under 10 amps. Clearly there will be line to line and line to neutral loads.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-2-20-Amp-Single-Pole-1-20-Amp-2-Pole-Quad-Tandem-Circuit-Breaker-HOMT2020220CP/100186179

Answer (score 3):

You have a MWBC that is currently wired for 120V-*only*. For those, two breakers with a "handle-tie" will suffice.

120V and 240V loads can mix on a MWBC if the breaker is 2-pole with *common trip* (handle-ties do not provide this functionality; it's an internal link mechanism inside the breaker). This is needed to keep a 240V load from re-energizing a leg that tripped.

They even [make receptacles for that.](https://www.gordonelectricsupply.com/index%7Etext%7E5588431%7Epath%7Eproduct%7Epart%7E5588431%7Eds%7Edept%7Eprocess%7Esearch?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIwuivvJm-3gIVB8JkCh2iJw3fEAQYBiABEgJnNfD_BwE)

[image]

*Note how there is no tab to break away on the visible side, since one must be neutral and the other L2.  However you can see the tab peeking out from the other side, which could both be L1 **of the same circuit.**. Because this is legal on MWBCs.*

---

As far as GFCI protection:  It's an easy job for a 2-pole GFCI breaker.  Replace the current non-GFCI 2-pole breaker in the service panel  with a 2-pole GFCI breaker.  Liberate the two GFCI receptacles and reuse them somewhere useful.

If you don't have space in your panel, then it's time to fit a subpanel *somewhere*. Since you're ready to do that, **do that**... just not out at the patio where it'll be a one-trick pony.  Next to the main service is better. After all, you have this "out of spaces" problem *all over your house*.  So fit it somewhere that makes sense for *all* your future loads.

I know adding a subpanel is a big job, "best" kicked on down the road for awhile longer... But the fact is you'll be right back here again when the wife wants an on-demand water heater or a plug-in hybrid.  In this day and age, with so many amazing electrical gadgets, a full panel is no place to be.

Comment: One potential fly -- if he has a non-common-trip quadruplex breaker, he can't do this, because the rules about common trip for mixed 120/240V loads on a MWBC apply circuit-wide.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel is there such a thing as a quadplex breaker (I assume on the outside breakers) that is "common maintenance shutoff" with the factory handle ties, *and yet not* common trip?

Comment: BR quadruplex breakers are available in common and independent trip versions (independent trip is BQxxxxxx, common trip is BQCxxxxxx)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel but an independent trip breaker would not have handle ties and would not have any pretense to common maintenance shutoff, yes?  Also, the coffee maker is not a 120/240 load, it is 240 only, I suspect from Europe. I thought that if alone, they didn't need common trip - do they need common trip when they are in an MWBC?  Of course MWBCs that serve only line-to-neutral loads only need common maint.s/o, not common trip.

Comment: The BQ220220 for instance still has inner and outer handle ties even though it is independent trip.  And it turns out that the rules in 210.4 only allow independent trip for line-to-line loads on a MWBC for a single device, as of 2017 (although they *do* allow independent trip for a single 120/240V load), which restricts the otherwise permissive rules in 240.15(B)(2) for line-to-line only loads

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel egads, factory-handle-tied independent trip exists in quads.  That's confusing.  At least OP will be OK provided he provisions one single NEMA 6 socket.   Your last sentence  adds an interesting twist to my old "what to do with all these 1-pole 30A breakers" question.  I guess I *can* use them handle-tied on one 120/240 loadsafter all.

Comment: The problem is that "one single load" means a dedicated branch circuit for a single outlet/device -- anything with more than one outlet or receptacle on it automatically has more than one load.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel good point.  So he *will* need common trip on his supply breaker.

Comment: OP here. Quad Breaker is a  Square D HOM DP--4075, one two pole and two one pole.  handle tie across the two inner breakers.

Comment: I thought that when two adjacent breakers fed a single12/3 with ground "romex wire", using the neutral as a common neutral, that it was then a MWBC. They are both 120V. Standard USA split phase 240V residential service. The question is never really answered clearly. Can I run low amp appliances at both 120V and 240V from these adjacent, handle tied, 20A breakers, at the same time?

Comment: @mcysr -- can you post a photo of the breaker in question?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I note that straight 120V-only MWBCs do not require common *trip*.  I also note that 240V-only loads do not require common *trip*.  So I want to confirm, you are saying when an MWBC supports both, such as one wired to the above-photographed plug, it *does* need common trip?

Comment: @Harper -- exactly, it requires common *trip* support.  Current production HOMT triplexes and quadplexes are common trip wherever they are common shutoff, but that's not true in some other lines (BR, mostly)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have seen the "Non common trip" markings on some quads,  but thought that applied to the outside set.

Comment: @Harper -- yeah, you really have to check the diagram/documentation for that specific breaker part number carefully

Comment: I hope this works. This is the breaker. center two are common trip.https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/bb37412c-34fe-4005-8530-dc2532e379cd/svn/square-d-quad-breakers-homt2020220cp-64_1000.jpg

Comment: OP here. I want to under stand this crystal clearly.  The two circuits arise from the center two breakers, sharing a neutral. It is clearly common trip. 20A. 3 conductor w ground romex. 12awg.  Is it legal, and reasonably safe, to power both a 220V coffee maker and one or two other 120V appliances, from a circuit like this?                         https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-2-20-Amp-Single-Pole-1-20-Amp-2-Pole-Quad-Tandem-Circuit-Breaker-HOMT2020220CP/100186179

Comment: Roger @mcysr readback is good, looks like a good plan.   You should be fine, just remember the 240V amperage applies to *both sides at once*, whereas 120V loads apply to the side they're plugged into.  Don't plan to exceed 20A.

Comment: Roger, thanks!  total amps of all appliances are less than 10A.

Comment: Thanks to everyone else too. I'm trying to parse the answers. It appears to hinge on the common trip issue of the two center breakers. they are clearly "common trip"

Comment: An MWBC that isn't known to be guarded by a common-trip breaker would be suitable only for use with 120V loads, so even though the potential difference between the outer legs would be 240V, I would think the phrase "120V MWBC" would seem appropriate for such a circuit.

Comment: @supercat good point! Edited.  (though I don't really make anything of that phrase).

Comment: I'd suggest replacing the parenthetical in your second paragraph, with a "...are allowed on MWBCs, but a 2-pole breaker with "common trip" is required (handle ties do not provide common trip).  It may be worthwhile to note the reason for the distinction: if an L1-neutral and an L1-L2 load are both present, current can flow through segments of the L1 wire between the two loads even when the L1 breaker is open.

Answer (score 1):

I would install a small "spa" panel then 2 breakers for each outlet and the double pole for the coffee maker. Because you are already feeding 12 AWG protected by 20 amps this would be legal as a sub. Make sure your neutrals are isolated from ground in the new panel, and install the panels prior to or at the split on the MWBC with there own breakers. For a clean install, you could continue with the MWBC from the spa panel but it needs to be a double pole if you do. I would take the easiest / least expensive path, but either will work.